# Use the return value of a function inside a if statement in mips

Tags: assembly, comparison, mips, return-value

How do I use the return value of a function in another function in mips? I know I have to use stacks but I am not sure how.

For example, if I have the code below:

```
int is_more_than_a_dozen(int a, int b) {
  if (sum(a, b) > 12)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I know how to do everything except for calling the function sum() in the if statement.

Thank you

---

Edit:

This is my sum function:

```
sum:
  add $v0, $a0, $a1
  jr $ra
```

Comment: The return value will be in `$v0` by convention. You do not need the stack for this.

Comment: so I need to use just beq to compare $v0 and a temporary var which holds 12? @Jester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use stacks.

Note that to call the function `sum`, you need registers `$a0` and `$a1`,  but the values you need are already in those two registers. So you just need to call the function and the parameters are already in the correct place.

You use `jal` to call a function and `jr` to return from a function. You can use `slti` to set the return value.

http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Comment: Thank you for the references link. In order to use SLTI, I need a $s and an imm (according to the references). If I set imm to be 12 (using li), can I just replace $s with $v0? @smac89

Comment: @user3142443 yes that is exactly what you need to do

Comment: You need to save your own return address somewhere before you `jal` (and restore at the end), otherwise your own `jr $ra` won't return to your caller.  Normally you'd use the stack, although since we know `sum` doesn't clobber any registers, you could just copy to another register.  (Although if you're depending on the internals of `sum` instead of just the calling convention, it's much easier to just inline `sum` entirely, defeating the purpose of the exercise in writing a non-leaf function.)